# Sinon and eslint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, sinon, eslint

I am writing unit tests for my angular app with Karma, Jasmine, and Sinon and I run eslint over my code base.

I define global variables that will be used in the `beforeEach inject` to create a `sinon.stub`. ESLint keeps complaining that my global variables are defined but never used. For example:

```
'getListStub' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
```

but in my code it looks like this

```
var listService, getListStub;

beforeEach(inject(function(_listService_) {
  listService = _listService_;
  getListStub = sinon.stub(listService, 'getList').returns(q.when(listResponse));
}
```

What is the best way to stop ESLint from producing errors?

Is setting `/*eslint no-unused-vars: 0*/` at the top of those testing files best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't using `getListStub` anywhere, why are you assigning it to a variable?

The properties of JS closure and memory management (specifically, holding referenced objects) will allow you to use `_listService_` directly and you shouldn't need to cache `getListStub`.

If that does work correctly with sinon, you should be able to rewrite your function as:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_listService_) {
  sinon.stub(_listService_, 'getList').returns(q.when(listResponse));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it!